# Rotate individual Kivy elements

Tags: python, kivy

I have a helper class that I use to spawn rotating images to the screen. The problem is, when I try to rotate the images, the whole layout rotates instead, although I do use PushMatrix and PopMatrix. They seem to have no effect and I cannot understand why.

I have also tried to separate everything with canvas.before and canvas.after, but got the same result.

The helper class:

```py
class WidgetDrawer(Widget):

    def __init__(self, imageStr, windowsize, **kwargs):
        super(WidgetDrawer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # this is part of the**kwargs notation
        # if you haven't seen with before, here's a link
        # http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.html
        self.WindowHeigth, self.WindowWidth = windowsize

        with self.canvas:
            PushMatrix()

            # setup a default size for the object
            self.size = (self.WindowWidth*.002*25, self.WindowWidth*.002*25)
            # center the widget
            self.pos = (self.center_x, self.center_y)
            self.rot = Rotate()
            self.rot.origin = self.pos
            self.rot.axis = (0, 0, 1)
            self.rot.angle = 30
            # this line creates a rectangle with the image drawn on top
            self.rect_bg = Rectangle(source=imageStr,
                                     pos=self.pos,
                                     size=self.size)
            PopMatrix()
            # this line calls the update_graphics_pos function every time the
            # position variable is modified
            self.bind(pos=self.update_graphics_pos)

            self.velocity_x = 0  # initialize velocity_x and velocity_y
            self.velocity_y = 0

    def update_graphics_pos(self, instance, value):
        # if the widgets position moves, the rectangle that contains the image
        # is also moved
        self.rect_bg.pos = value

    # use this function to change widget position
    def setPos(self, xpos, ypos):
        self.x = xpos
        self.y = ypos

    def move(self):
        self.x = self.x + self.velocity_x
        self.y = self.y + self.velocity_y

        if self.y > self.WindowHeigth*0.95:
            # don't let the ship go up too high
            self.y = self.WindowHeigth*0.95
        if self.y <= 0:
            self.y = 0  # set heigth to 0 if ship too low

    def update(self):
        # the update function moves the astreoid. Other things could happen
        # here as well (speed changes for example)
        self.move()
```

Edit: added minimal reproducible example of the above class in being used: The bellow code spawns items that go from right lo left (and should rotate, but instead the whole layout rotates)

```py
from kivy.config import Config

# don't make the app re-sizeable
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions import Rectangle
from kivy.properties import partial
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import PopMatrix, PushMatrix, Rotate

from random import randint


class WidgetDrawer(Widget):
    # This widget is used to draw all of the objects on the screen
    # it handles the following:
    # widget movement, size, positioning
    # whever a WidgetDrawer object is created, an image string needs to be
    # specified, along with the windowsize tuple
    # example:    wid - WidgetDrawer('./image.png', (Window.height, Window.width))
    # windowsize is used for the default size and position,
    # but can pe updated later

    def __init__(self, imageStr, windowsize, **kwargs):
        super(WidgetDrawer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # this is part of the**kwargs notation
        # if you haven't seen with before, here's a link
        # http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.html
        self.WindowHeigth, self.WindowWidth = windowsize

        with self.canvas:
            PushMatrix()

            # setup a default size for the object
            self.size = (self.WindowWidth*.002*25, self.WindowWidth*.002*25)
            # center the widget
            self.pos = (self.center_x, self.center_y)
            self.rot = Rotate()
            self.rot.origin = self.pos
            self.rot.axis = (0, 0, 1)
            self.rot.angle = 30
            # this line creates a rectangle with the image drawn on top
            self.rect_bg = Rectangle(source=imageStr,
                                     pos=self.pos,
                                     size=self.size)
            PopMatrix()
            # this line calls the update_graphics_pos function every time the
            # position variable is modified
            self.bind(pos=self.update_graphics_pos)

            self.velocity_x = 0  # initialize velocity_x and velocity_y
            self.velocity_y = 0

    def update_graphics_pos(self, instance, value):
        # if the widgets position moves, the rectangle that contains the image
        # is also moved
        self.rect_bg.pos = value

    # use this function to change widget position
    def setPos(self, xpos, ypos):
        self.x = xpos
        self.y = ypos

    def move(self):
        self.x = self.x + self.velocity_x
        self.y = self.y + self.velocity_y

        if self.y > self.WindowHeigth*0.95:
            # don't let the ship go up too high
            self.y = self.WindowHeigth*0.95
        if self.y <= 0:
            self.y = 0  # set heigth to 0 if ship too low

    def update(self):
        # the update function moves the astreoid. Other things could happen
        # here as well (speed changes for example)
        self.move()


class Asteroid(WidgetDrawer):
    # Asteroid class. The flappy ship will dodge these
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def update(self):
        # self.rot.angle += 1  # this should animate the object, but rotates the layout
        super().update()


class Game(Widget):
    # this is the main widget that contains the game.
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Game, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.windowsize = (Window.height, Window.width)
        self.asteroidList = []  # use this to keep track of asteroids
        self.minProb = 1700  # this variable used in spawning asteroids

    def addAsteroid(self):
        # add an asteroid to the screen
        # self.asteroid
        imageNumber = randint(1, 4)
        imageStr = './sandstone_'+str(imageNumber)+'.png'  #change the image here
        tmpAsteroid = Asteroid(imageStr, self.windowsize)
        tmpAsteroid.x = Window.width*0.99

        # randomize y position
        ypos = randint(0, 16)

        ypos = ypos*Window.height*.0625

        tmpAsteroid.y = ypos
        tmpAsteroid.velocity_y = 0
        vel = 10
        tmpAsteroid.velocity_x = -0.1*vel

        self.asteroidList.append(tmpAsteroid)
        self.add_widget(tmpAsteroid)

    def update(self, dt):
        # This update function is the main update function for the game
        # All of the game logic has its origin here
        # events are setup here as well

        # update game objects

        # update asteroids
        # randomly add an asteroid
        tmpCount = randint(1, 1800)
        if tmpCount > self.minProb:
            self.addAsteroid()
        if self.minProb < 1700:
            self.minProb = 1900
        self.minProb = self.minProb - 1

        for k in self.asteroidList:
            if k.x < -20:
                self.remove_widget(k)
                self.asteroidList.remove(k)

            k.update()


class ClientApp(App):
    def build(self):
        # this is where the root widget goes
        # should be a canvas
        parent = Widget()  # this is an empty holder for buttons, etc
        Window.clearcolor = (0, 0, 0, 1.)

        game = Game()
        # Start the game clock (runs update function once every (1/60) seconds
        # Clock.schedule_interval(app.update, 1.0/60.0)
        parent.add_widget(game)
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0/60.0)
        # use this hierarchy to make it easy to deal w/buttons
        return parent


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ClientApp().run()
```

Comment: Your code does look reasonable, could you provide a minimal runnable example?

Comment: @inclement Sure, updated the question to include a runnable minimal example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code rotates all your `Asteroids` by the same amount and that rotation does not vary as time goes on. You can fix that by updating the rotation with every call to `update()`. Try modifying your code like this:

First define a `delta_angle` for each Asteroid in its `__init__()` method:

```
self.delta_angle = randint(-3, 3)
```

This gives each `Asteroid` its own random rotation.

Then create a method to actually update the rotation in the `WidgetDrawer`:

```
def rotate(self):
    self.rot.origin = self.center
    self.rot.angle += self.delta_angle
```

Then call this new method from the `update()` method:

```
def update(self):
    # the update function moves the astreoid. Other things could happen
    # here as well (speed changes for example)
    self.move()
    self.rotate()
```

Now, each `Asteroid` should rotate independently as time passes.